# Android java - Is it possible to open a file automatically?

Tags: java, android

I have an android app where the user selects a file which creates a URI.

The URI is then used to read the file into a buffer.

I can get the URI-string by doing `uri.toString();`

The URI-string looks like:
`content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A12858`

To make things quicker, for development purposes, I want to hardcode the URI-string and use it in reverse order to generate the URI.
Is this possible?

---

EDIT1:

Here is the code to get the `data_uri` for the selected file:

```
// at this point the user has the uri (after clicking on the button and selecting file)
Uri uri = intent.getData();
InputStream stream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
byte[] byteArray = JasonHelper.readBytes(stream);
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append("data:image/jpeg;base64,");
stringBuilder.append(encoded);
String data_uri = stringBuilder.toString();
```

I can get the `data_uri` after I select a file.

---

EDIT2:

The problem is that I want to start with hardcoded uri (for development purposes).
I run the program once and get the value of the content uri string.
I then hardcode the uriStr  and set uri1 from it:

```
String uriStr = "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A13819";
Uri uri1 = Uri.parse(uriStr);
```

I restart the program but the value of uri1 is different from the value of the uri from the original run.
For example:  the values of the fields authority, fragment, path are null where before they had some values (see snapshot).

According to [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) Uri Access Lifetime is only for the duration of the app (and even shorter).

In my case, the origin is a file uri and I assume that the file does not move.
Can I hard-code anything such that the file can be opened after the program restarts without having to select the file again?

[image]

Comment: That was not uri.getPath() but uri.toString().

Comment: Of course you can hard code any string value. But as it is a content scheme you probably have no read access after restart of your app.

Comment: So to get read access after restart of the app, is it possible to generate a uri from a hardcoded file path? (instead of having to manually click and select the file every time)

Comment: I cannot follow you. But lets start at the begin. Please show your code to let the user select the file. Then show how you save the uri string so you can use it after restart. Put all in your post. Dont put code in a comment

Comment: @blackapps, I edited my post with the code.

Comment: I organized my code again.  
Please let me know if you understand my code so far and I will then continue to describe my problem.

Comment: Why didn't you tell that you read the contents of a file, encode it base64 and put the result in a String instance using a string builder. You did not even tell if your code works.

Comment: This code works. Can I proceed to describe my problem? Does my post make sense so far?

Comment: Now save uri.toString() to shared preferences. Then later get that string back from shared preferences. String uriSting = pref.getString ("whatever"); then Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString); Use uri as you did before. All this has been said also before. Nothing to hardcode. Just reuse uri. (You will get an exception but that we will handle then).

Comment: Can I get the string from shared preferences after I restart the app?
I want to restart the app and then get the uriString.

Comment: I edited this question and the OP still added *Android-java* to it again. Don't put tags inside a question's title !

Comment: I understood only the title of this question. The rest sounds like rocket science to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html)
I now understand that content uri cannot be used when the app restarts.
But if the content is saved to the file system, e.g. to the internal storage of the app, then assuming the read permissions are ok, the file can be openned programatically by providing the file path.

Answer (score 0):

I got nothing on whatever you said, but you should probably be using `Uri.parse(...)`

Something like `Uri.parse(myURL)`

Comment: Yeah, you definitely should use `Uri.parse(string_uri)` to get a URI object

Comment: @Noah if I hardcode the content uri string, after restarting the program, the new uri is invalid (see EDIT2)